# Figure with two graphics and one matrix

Tags: tables, floats

I want to recreate this figure in latex: https://developer.nvidia.com/discover/convolution
I dont quite managed to algin the matrix and the images.

This is how I tried it:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
   \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Grundlagen/Bilder/Freature_1.png}
        &
        $\displaystyle
            \begin{bmatrix}
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\
                -1 & 8 & -1 \\
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\
            \end{bmatrix}
        $
        &    
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Grundlagen/Bilder/Freature_2.png}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

I would appreciate any help.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that a `tabular` is vertically centered with respect to the baseline (actually, not exactly, but it's not so important).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  Input image &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} Convolution \\ kernel \end{tabular} &
  Feature map \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular} &
  $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & -1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 8 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ &    
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\caption{How the convolution kernel works}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` and `adjustbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{width=82mm,
                colsep=3pt, 
                colspec={X[c] X[c, mode=dmath] X[c] },
                row{1} = {mode=text} 
                }
    Input image & Convolution Kernel & Feature map  \\
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-a}
        &   \begin{bmatrix}
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\
                -1 & \hfill 8 & -1 \\
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\
            \end{bmatrix} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-b}
    \end{tblr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{M{2.5cm}  M{2.6cm}  M{2.5cm}}
        Input image & Convolution Kernel & Feature map\\[0.5cm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        &%
        \vfill$\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix}
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\
                -1 & \hfill 8 & -1 \\
                -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 
        \end{bmatrix}$\vfill
        &  
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: correct output]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to add the text above the images aswell and with your approch the text is not centered?

Comment: @HWilmer Update the answer.